# Pre-run animation on page load

Tags: javascript, html, css

The first time I run my animation it runs at about 5fps and looks really janky. Is there a way to run it whilst the page loads or instantly after loading?

Also I have tried preloading the images with a preload in the header of my html. No luck with that.

My animation has three images that start with no width or height or opacity, but grow and become visible  once the corresponding text-option is clicked. This creates the effect of the image growing from either the left or right of the container.

When loading the page, the first image (the one with active class) appears and is clearly loaded. When you then click a different text option, then the image expands but at a very slow rate. Once this image is loaded, then it never has this problem until the next refresh. So I would have assumed it would be a matter of preloading the image, but when I tried to preload the image with this `<link rel="preload" href="img.png" as="image">` nothing had changed.

Here is a video to show the problem: [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GnxXyZLf_2A)

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const textOption = document.querySelectorAll(".text-option");
  const selectableImage = document.querySelectorAll(".selectable-image");

  function clickedTextOption(clickedOption) {
    textOption.forEach((option, index) => {
      const active = option.classList.toggle("active", option === clickedOption);
      selectableImage[index].classList.toggle('active', active);
    });
  }

  textOption.forEach(option => {
    option.addEventListener("click", () => {
      clickedTextOption(option);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.section-2 {
  display: flex;
  background-color: var(--second-background);
  padding: min(100px, 3svw);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 60vh;
}

.section-2 .image-container {
  width: 50svw;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.section-2 .image-container img {
  width: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.section-2 .image-container .selectable-image.active {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.section-2 .text-selection-container {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: min(50px, 2svw);
  padding-left: 0;
}

.section-2 .text-selection-container .text-option {
  margin: 1svw;
  padding-left: min(50px, 2svw);
}

.section-2 .text-selection-container .text-option .title {
  font-size: 2svw;
  margin-bottom: 0.5svw;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.section-2 .text-selection-container .text-option .description {
  font-size: 1svw;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.section-2 .text-selection-container .text-option.active {
  border-left: 4px solid var(--primary);
  padding-left: calc(min(50px, 2svw) - 4px)
}
```

```html
<section class="section-2">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="img.png" alt="" class="selectable-image active">
    <img src="img.png" alt="" class="selectable-image">
    <img src="img.png" alt="" class="selectable-image">
  </div>
  <div class="text-selection-container">
    <div class="text-option active">
      <p class="title">Title</p>
      <p class="description">Description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="text-option">
      <p class="title">Title</p>
      <p class="description">Description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="text-option">
      <p class="title">Title</p>
      <p class="description">Description</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

P.S. img.png is just a placeholder

How would be the best way to prevent this lag on load?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that the problem there is not the image. From what I understood your frames show but they update slowly. If the image was not loaded then it would not display a frame at all. I think your problem is layout changes during the page load are slower because of all the JS running. Try using GPU powered animations with only transform and opacity and it will be much better if that's the case.

Comment: The concept that it isn't the images but the actual animation slowing it down is interesting, but all my JS is doing is listening for a click on the div, then applying the active class to the element so that the animation is only using opacity and width. Nothing else. So i would be surprised if that was the problem.

Comment: Looks like your source image is substantially larger than its container - try with an image with substantially smaller dimensions (width/height) (at least to see if that fixes it).   The browser needs to recalculate each animation step and with large files, that's not that quick.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just ended up automatically cycling through the whole animation on page load and added the first active image as a cover image to hide it from any fast scrollers:
HTML:

```
<div class="cover-image"></div>
<img src="img.png" alt="" class="selectable-image active">
<img src="img.png" alt="" class="selectable-image">
<img src="img.png" alt="" class="selectable-image">
```

CSS:

```
    .cover-image {
      background: url(img.png) center/cover;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: 1;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    
    .cover-image.visible {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    .selectable-image {
      width: 0%;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
    .selectable-image.active {
      opacity: 1 !important;
      width: 100% !important;
    }
    .selectable-image.auto-active {
      opacity: 1 !important;
      width: 100% !important;
    }
```

JS:

```
function setStyles() {
    selectableImage.forEach((imgNum, index) => {
      setTimeout(function () {
        imgNum.classList.add("auto-active");
        console.log("completed" + imgNum);

        // Remove the "auto-active" class after 0.5 seconds
        setTimeout(function () {
          imgNum.classList.remove("auto-active");
        }, 500);
      }, 500 * index);
    });

    coverImage.classList.add("visible");

    setTimeout(function () {
      coverImage.classList.remove("visible");
    }, 700 * selectableImage.length);

    console.log("ended");
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You can use `<img style='display:none' src=` and it will load into browser memory/cache but not show in the browser.  Just need to remove the `display:none` when it comes to show the image (can also do with add/remove a class instead of inline style).  *Might* work better than a "cover".